# Aggregates with inner join issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues getting the aggregate function to work with this AdventureWorks database example.  I'm attempting to get shipping methods whose annual total due is greater than 5 million but when I uncomment number of employees and distinct number of employees, both total dues end up the same.  Could anyone give me some help so I can understand what i need to do?  I've tried CTE and over() but the aggregates didn't agree with me then.  Thank you.

```
USE AdventureWorks2014

SELECT  DISTINCT S.Name   AS 'ShippingMethod', 
  dt.OrderYear AS 'OrderYear', 
  dt.[Total Due]   AS 'Total Due', 
  dt.[Average Total Due]   AS 'Average Total Due',
  dt.[Number Of Employees]  AS 'Number Of Employees',
  dt.[Distinct Number of Employees]   AS 'Distinct Number of Employees'

FROM Purchasing.ShipMethod AS S

INNER join
(SELECT 
  s.Name    AS 'ShippingMethod', 
  YEAR(P.OrderDate) AS 'OrderYear', 
  SUM(p.TotalDue)   AS 'Total Due', 
  AVG(p.TotalDue)   AS 'Average Total Due',
  COUNT(p.EmployeeID)  AS 'Number Of Employees',
  p.VendorID   AS 'Distinct Number of Employees'
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader AS P
 inner JOIN Purchasing.ShipMethod AS S
  ON  P.ShipMethodID = S.ShipMethodID --AND p.[Total Due]=p.[Average Total Due]

 group by s.Name, p.OrderDate, p.VendorID --,p.EmployeeID --/*p.TotalDue,*/----,p.VendorID
-- having SUM(p.TotalDue) > 5000000
)  
AS dt 
ON S.Name = dt.ShippingMethod --AND dt.[Total Due]=dt.[Average Total Due]
WHERE  dt.[Total Due] > 5000000  and dt.OrderYear = '2014'--dt.[Total Due] BETWEEN dt.OrderYear  5000000
ORDER BY dt.[Total Due] DESC, OrderYear --dt.[Total Due] DESC--YEAR(dt.OrderYear) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

what about that group by for orderyear?  (group by s.Name, **YEAR(P.OrderDate)**, p.VendorID)

```
SELECT 
  s.Name    AS 'ShippingMethod', 
  YEAR(P.OrderDate) AS 'OrderYear', 
  SUM(p.TotalDue)   AS 'Total Due', 
  AVG(p.TotalDue)   AS 'Average Total Due',
  COUNT(p.EmployeeID)  AS 'Number Of Employees',
  p.VendorID   AS 'Distinct Number of Employees'
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader AS P
 inner JOIN Purchasing.ShipMethod AS S
  ON  P.ShipMethodID = S.ShipMethodID --AND p.[Total Due]=p.[Average Total Due]

 group by s.Name, YEAR(P.OrderDate), p.VendorID
```

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed the total due and average due being the same value.  I now need to figure out how to group by shipping method as well so it totals the yearly due.  Thanks again!

Comment: could you use a window function to run your yearly totals over what you have?  ...without an additional group by